# A movie about relationship between a male convict and a female teacher

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for a movie that a romantic relationship between a soon-to be released male convict and a single middle aged female teacher. It was made in late 80s or 90s. But the time in the movie should be earlier than that because black people were treated like second class citizens. It could be an American, Irish or British movie.

His sentence was ending and he was allowed to pay his last days in public service. He had to repair and repaint the outside of houses. A couple of guards were always watching him  during his work. He was black, muscled, had a short black hair, between 25-35, had medium height.

One of the houses was owned by a single female teacher. The house was on a little high level near to the seaside without close houses around . She was white, in her 40s, long brown haired, had a glasses, medium sized. She proposed to give him basic lessons about reading, writing, literature, etc. exchange his services. One day she was washing her head with shampoo and the water has gone suddenly. She called him for help. He checked on the water system and said "I can't do much now, I can put some water in a little washtub and wash your hair if you want." She replied "Ok, do it." When he was washing her hair, he touched her body too and their relationship started at that moment. He said to her ' Your skin is so soft ' or something like that .

He finished his sentence and they start to live together. She was so nice to her, bought some clothes, taught him lost of lessons, gave him some money to spend. Her only wish was from him to stay with her. However she was so jealous of him and acting overprotective. He got bored of her attitude and fell in love with another lady. The lady was black like him and they decided to live together.

She got so angry and prepared a cruel plan. She said to the authorities that he raped and beat her. She thought that she'll win the trail easily because of he's black and just released from the prison . The police arrested him and a trial began. I couldn't remember how the trial has ended. Does anyone know this movie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the exact plot of [Passion and Prejudice](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0283535/combined) from 2001.

> When prim and proper New England college professor Gwen Barry (Titanic's Frances Fisher) hires handsome young prison inmate Dalton Roy (Derwin Jordan) to tend her yard through a prison work furlough program, their mentor-student relationship soon turns into a passionate love affair. But when Dalton completes his prison sentence, meets a pretty young college student (Kandyse McClure), and attempts to start over again on his own, Gwen becomes obsessed with remaining a part of Dalton's life or destroying it completely.

Here's the trailer, where you can see the girl he falls for and the professor's nefarious scheme: